# Editing PHP Form

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Option Dropdown set Option to One Stored in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332946/php-option-dropdown-set-option-to-one-stored-in-db)

I have a form that I am using to edit data from mysql table. Everything works nicely, but I'm struggling to work out how to load one of the returned value and insert it into a dropdown list I have a dropdown that contains these items (Accepted/Denied/Pending/New). Only one of these values is inserted into the table. My question is by using a select statement, how do I display or show this value in a dropdown list so that the user can choose something else from the list

I've got a HTML drop down box as similar to this:

```
<select name="dropdown">
<option>Accepted</option>
<option>Denied</option>
<option>Pending</option>
<option>New</option>
</select>
```

If I run a mysql query and get a result of "Pending", is there anyway using PHP to give Pending the selected value?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking about how to create a dropdown list in HTML?

Comment: Please show the code for your form, tell us what you tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: I know how to create a drop downmenu. But my problem is that when I do a select statement, I want the value returned to be the one that is shown as selected in the dropdown menu. Not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: @Helen: This is really unclear.  You want to perform a `SELECT` query based on the value that the user chose in the dropdown list?

Comment: Can you show us your php script? you've stated "process.php" but we dont really know what's in there.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

You can use this to make option as selected.

Comment: Thank you. But that is preselected already...my question is along those lines, but I want to dynamically select the value that's return from my select statement in my mysql.

Comment: Well, I gave you direction. It was all up to you to insert it into some php script. All you had to do is, when loading page, generate dropdown list with php and insert 'selected' tag where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is basic php ... There is no difficulty doing an `if` statement like this:

```
<?php
// Fetch the result, and care about security for sql queries ...
// I just show you a quick example, but it's bad practice
$sqlResult = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SELECT yourField FROM yourTable WHERE yourId = $id") );
$valueToCheck = $sqlResult['yourField'];

function selected($value,$toCheck){
    echo "value='$value'";
    if($value = $toCheck)
        echo " selected='selected'";
}    
?>
<select>
     <option <?php selected('Accepted',$valueToCheck); ?>>Accepted</option>
     <option <?php selected('Denied',$valueToCheck); ?>>Denied</option>
</select>
```

I hope it will help you ...

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using AJAX? There is a thing called MATE (MYSQL AJAX TABLE EDITOR). It more or less does what you want (and much much more) and is highly customizable. http://www.mysqlajaxtableeditor.com.

Otherwise you try this

Your html would be something like this

```
<form action="process.php" method='post'>
<select name="colours">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Your process.php would pull or save the value that was selected by running

```
$_POST['colours']
```

and that should get you to do what you need

You would then do the following to get it saved into your sql database

```
$colour=$_POST['colours']

$sql="INSERT INTO your_table (`colours`) VALUES ($colours)";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Read my question :( I'm not looking for how to post. Rather, I'm selecting from a table and want the result to be the item that displays as selected in the dropdown menu

Comment: do you want this information to load on the same page? if so you need ajax and it's beyond the scope of this post. Otherwise you do the same thing as post except your WHERE statement will have the value from the dropdown passed into it.